# Node js Buffers for incoming data

Tags: node.js

I am wondering if it makes sense to use Node's Buffer for incoming client data to a server. My server and clients are TCP based and I am using `<EOF>` to  determine the end of a message. The message is always stringified JSON.

eg: `{"name":"Bob"}<EOF>`

In case the entire message does not come through, should I be using Node Buffer to build up the data, or a regular string?

If it is a buffer, I don't think I understand how to correctly build one up.  This is my `Client` constructor that is created each time a socket connects to the Node server.

```
constructor(socket){
    var self = this;

    // properties
    this.socket = socket;

    this.buffer = Buffer.alloc(1024);
    this.dataEnd = '<EOF>';

    // append <EOF> to every msg
    this.socket.write = function(msg){
        msg += "<EOF>";
        return Socket.prototype.write.call(this, msg);
    };

    // build up buffer
    this.socket.on('data', function(data){
        var buffLen = self.buffer.length;
        var dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data);
        if(buffLen + dataBuffer.length < 1024){
            if(data.indexOf(self.dataEnd) === -1){
                self.buffer.concat(dataBuffer);
            }
        }
    });

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Buffers are primarily for streams of binary data, there's no point in using a buffer for a string.

Comment: Well let's say I'm running a Node js server and expect 100s to 1000s of clients sending messages every few seconds between server and client. Should I not be building up there messages in buffers? What's to say I get the full message, etc.. ?

Comment: Is there a problem with your current code that you need help with? (It looks pretty reasonable... if your question is just "Is it okay to use a buffer to buffer the data?" the answer is "Yes.")

Comment: Reading the question again, I think I didn't quite get it. You're using TCP duplex streams, which in themselves are buffering and sending octets. You're reading and writing to the stream, so you don't really know when a message ends, hence why you add `<EOF>` to the end of each message. As you receive data, you won't always  get the entire message in one go, and you need to build it up until you see a `<EOF>` so you know that the message is complete. If so, yes, it's fine to use buffers for that.

Comment: Yes that's correct. But.. maybe I am just asking -  am I using buffers right? I am always creating a new buffer and concating to the static one. I was hoping to find something more like c#'s StringBuilder where I could just push to the end of the buffer..?